# What's this error from a closed kinematic chain in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, urdf, sdformat, sdf

I was implementing closed kinematic chains for my URDF by including an SDF description of the robot's links and joints within the `gazebo` tag. The URDF and robot model seem to load/work fine (one link keeps phasing through every other link while moving as a ball joint but that's another problem), but my terminal spams the following error:

```
[Wrn] [Joint.cc:821] failed to find a clean set of connected links, i.e. this joint is inside a loop, cannot SetPosition kinematically.
[Dbg] [Link.cc:1686] we have a loop! cannot find nice subset of connected links, this link link_A connects back to parent link_B.
```

What does this error mean; why is it happening? What can I do to learn more about it/fix it?

Comment: can you share the URDF that is causing this error?